# Cannot bind view from binding adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I'm trying to bind view from adapter but it throws error

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="accessHistoryItem"
            type="com.example.api.model.response.AccessListItem" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="122dp"
        android:layout_margin="30dp">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/borderLine"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:background="@color/black"
            app:borderLine="@{accessHistoryItem}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

binding adapter

```
    @BindingAdapter("borderLine")
    fun View.borderLine(item: AccessListItem?){
        item.let {
    
        }
```

exception

> Cannot find a setter for <android.view.View app:borderLine> that accepts parameter type 'com.example.api.model.response.AccessListItem'
> If a binding adapter provides the setter, check that the adapter is annotated correctly and that the parameter type matches.
> Open File

gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 19
        versionName "0.7.1"

        testInstrumentationRunner 
"androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        applicationVariants.all{
            variant ->
                variant.outputs.each{
                    output->
                        project.ext { appName = 'example' }
                        def formattedDate = new Date().format('dd-MM-yyyy')
                        // on below line we are creating a new name for our apk.
                        def newName = output.outputFile.name
                        newName = newName.replace("app-", "$project.ext.appName-v${variant.versionName}_${variant.versionCode}-$formattedDate-")
                        output.outputFileName  = newName
                }
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    dataBinding{
        enabled = true
    }

}

dependencies {

    implementation project(":api")

    //rx
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.9'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'

    //gson
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'

    //glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'

    api 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06'

    apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'


}
```

Comment: From the first look there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code. Can you include your app-level `build.gradle` file? (the one where you define your libraries)

Comment: I updated post with gradle properties

Answer (score 1):

From your provided code snippets, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with it. I suspect missing plugin in the app-level build gradle file. Add `id 'kotlin-kapt'` to the plugins.

Comment: I did, but same

Comment: I don't see in your gradle file the dependency on the `androidx.databinding` library where the `@BindingAdapter` is defined. Aren't you missing the `kapt "androidx.databinding:databinding-common:$databinding_version"` dependency?

Comment: no because I just added one textView in xml and tried to bind it from adapter and it works but, on this view it doesn't works

Comment: I replicated your code locally (except for the `:api` module, because I don't have it) and it run fine, without any crash. So maybe you have some corrupted cache. Try Android Studio -> File -> Invalidate Cache/Restart ... and select restart, then rerun your project

Comment: If you can push your project to github for example, I can help you further. Otherwise from the provided code nothing appears wrong to me, I used your exact code base and it works on my local devices.